# IE11 doesn't drop :hover for bootstrap button on mouse leave

Tags: angular, hover, internet-explorer-11, ng-bootstrap

Our client rised a "bug". The bug is about having one button stuck with blue background (hovered) even after a pointer was moved outside.

I've created a MWE locally and moved it to [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v8nufw?file=src/app/app.component.html) (sorry, not working on IE, lol).

I've also add links to YouTube videos to show the issue as it turned out You had some hard time reproducing it.

To reproduce locally, just create a new Angular project , `ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`.

Angular 11,
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.0.2",
"bootstrap": "^4.6.0",

Here is the view **app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  toggle: boolean;
}
```

Here is the view **app.component.html**:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="toggle">
    <button *ngSwitchCase="true" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="toggle = !toggle" ngbPopover="You see, I show up on hover1!" placement="right" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave">Primary1</button>
    <button *ngSwitchDefault type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="toggle = !toggle" ngbPopover="You see, I show up on hover2!" placement="right" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave">Primary2</button>
</div>
```

Key points:

- having two buttons
- button 1 on click will be hidden, button 2 will be showed
- button 2 on click will be hidden, button 1 will be showed
- button 1 and 2 have different bootstrap styles to make things simple
- both buttons displays a tooltip on hover, dismiss them on leave

How to reproduce:

- click on button
- immediately after click move a mouse on tooltip (but You need to be very, very fast)

Effect:

- button 1 is hidden (removed from DOM),
- button 2 is shown (added to DOM),
- button 2 is not hovered,
- tooltips are dismissed
- IE **still** aplies `.btn-outline-primary:hover` even the button is not hovered,
- hovering over the button and moving pointer out fixes the issue - IE will apply `.btn-outline-primary`  as expected.

[image]
[image]
[image]

What we think? That IE after adding button 2 is not aware that user already move cursor out (so IE "thinks" that no hover state was changed, so it keeps the :hover styling but the button is different). BUT `mouseleave` and `mouseout` is fired for the new button.

We weren't able to reproduce on Chrome after many many tries.

What we have tried:

- we dissabled transisions - Chrome by default is adding [prefers-reduced-motion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion) media query, IE is not supported. That fixed blinking effect but hover issue remains.
- we tried to separate the button to component and call `detectChanges` with/without `setTimeout` to let IE "rethink" the situation and then rerender the button with proper styles - didn't help
- ultimately I have added a switch like this:

```
    <div [ngSwitch]="forceRefresh">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="true">...</div>
        <div *ngSwitchDefault>...</div>
    </div>
```

and I change `forceRefresh` value from `false` to `true` in `setTimeout` to force IE to think it has to render entirely different DOM (both cases renders the same button). It worked.

I would like to know is there more elegant way to workaround this IE-specific issue?

Note: In our project this happens even after removing tooltops, so I doubt it is connected with [Bootstrap popovers](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples). I assume it can be fixed easiliy by keeping only one button but then we will have to apply many conditional expressions for each attribute for such a button. Using `ng-templates` for grouping buttons is much more preferable.

Video (from home, MWE, Chrome, IE11, Edge): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oeG-11TzS-Q

Comment: Do you mean the issue is that Primary2 background is still blue when the mouse pointer out? Correct me if I'm wrong. If so, I made some tests in IE 11 but it seems that the result is the same as Chrome's. You can check my screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXEPc.gif. I can't reproduce the issue. I test with Angular10, "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^8.0.4", "bootstrap": "^4.5.0".

Comment: This is exactly the problem here. I know it is hard to reproduce it. It's even harder on a complete empty component. I'll upload a video (lol) on it. At work we are using Angular 9, we have branch with 10, I tested at home on 11, so it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: I've added links for videos that illustrates the issue on IE.

Comment: I can reproduce it now. It's quite hard to reproduce as it works sometimes. Now I think it's not related with Angular version and bootstrap version. It's more like an issue with ng-bootstrap in IE. I suggest that you can also raise an issue in ng-bootstrap github.

Comment: Do I want to contribute to long lived king of the browsers which every developer would love to bury alive? But I guess just for curiocity sake this is some idea. Anyway, thanks for showing some interest and putting effort to reproduce